# UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: method error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, uialertview

```
  - (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated{
if (0 == [alerts cancelButtonIndex]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
} else if (1 == [alerts cancelButtonIndex]) {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

}

I have a UIAlertView, here is the initialization of alerts:

```
alerts = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Trumpets" message:@"Are you sure you would like to use one trumpet, this will give you 10 random units" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alerts show];
```

The error is Expected ')' before '(' token

I don't understand, the NSLogs were to help remember which option was which. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: In your code above I don't see a close brace '}' for the dismiss method.  Is that right or you just did not paste all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ending bracket:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated{
    if ([alerts cancelButtonIndex] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else if ([alerts cancelButtonIndex] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```